# Couldn't deduce template paramter even if it is known at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, constexpr, template-meta-programming

I have a variadic template class `SomeClass` that looks like this (basically):

```
template<std::size_t SIZE_>
class SomeClass {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t SIZE = SIZE_;
};
```

It has a constexpr member that simply contains the `std::size_t` template parameter used to instantiate it. I want a `constexpr` function that can sum all the sizes of `SomeClass<SIZE_>` specializatins. My first idea was to make a simple variadic template function that adds all the `SIZE`s like that:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t totalSize() {
    return T::SIZE;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t totalSize() {
    return totalSize<T>() + totalSize<Ts...>();
}
```

Now I try to call it:

```
constexpr std::size_t size = totalSize<SomeClass<1>, SomeClass<2>, SomeClass<3>>()    // should return 6
```

It turns at that the last parameter unpacking makes call to `totalSize<T>` function ambiguous because both template `totalSize` functions match it. Fine, I modified my code to have two distinct functions and came up with this:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t totalSizeSingle() {
    return T::SIZE;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t totalSize() {
    std::size_t result = totalSizeSingle<T>();
    if (sizeof...(Ts) > 0) result += totalSize<Ts...>();
    return result;
}
```

Again, the last unpacking seem to be problematic. Apparently, `T` can't be deduced even though it is known at compile time. I get the following error (compiling with GCC):

```
In instantiation of 'constexpr std::size_t totalSize() [with T = SomeClass<3>; Ts = {}; std::size_t = long long unsigned int]':
main.cpp:129:51:   required from here
main.cpp:134:82:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'totalSize<SomeClass<1>, SomeClass<2>, SomeClass<3> >()'
main.cpp:129:51:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'totalSize<SomeClass<2>, SomeClass<3> >()'
main.cpp:129:58: error: no matching function for call to 'totalSize<>()'
  129 |         if (sizeof...(Ts) > 0) result += totalSize<Ts...>();
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
main.cpp:127:23: note: candidate: 'template<class T, class ... Ts> constexpr std::size_t totalSize()'
  127 | constexpr std::size_t totalSize() {
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:127:23: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:129:58: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
  129 |         if (sizeof...(Ts) > 0) result += totalSize<Ts...>();
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

I don't really understand why it is not working. Every type is know at compile time. Why is this happening and how can I get it to work? I'm using C++11.

Comment: Non-constexpr if can't help you. Use `enable_if` with `sizeof...(Ts) > 0` or make the template header with 3 parameters, 2 singles and the last one variadic.

Comment: If only you could update to c++17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Comment: Make your if constexpr: `if constexpr(whatever)`. But a better solution would be fold expressions: `return ((T::SIZE)+...+(Ts::SIZE));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a reason people call `struct`s *metafunctions* in c++ template metaprogramming.

In our case the major advantage of doing metaprogramming in a struct is that resolving function overloading by template arguments is different and more limited than that of class specialisation.

So I suggest:

```
template <class ...> // only called if there's no arguments
struct add_sizes {
    static constexpr auto value = 0;
};

template <class T, class ... Ts>
struct add_sizes <T, Ts...> {
    static constexpr auto value = T::SIZE + add_sizes<Ts...>::value;
};

// then wrap it into your function:

template <class ... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t totalSize () {
    return add_sizes<Ts...>::value;
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6YnaG7986)

---

Another advantage of using structs is for easy "return" of multiple values or types, which for functions gets complicated. Sometimes by calculating **A** you've already calculated **B**, so it can make sense to store both.

In general I'd say that if you're ever struggling solving a metaprogramming problem with functions, switch to structs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when the template argument list is of size 1 `totalSize<Ts...>();` would call `totalSize<>()` but `totalSize<>();` is not defined.

You could make your first version work by making it take 2 or make template arguments.

```
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t totalSize() {
    return T::SIZE;
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t totalSize() {
    return totalSize<T>() + totalSize<U, Ts...>();
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e629198447befe6)